# How can I display multiple amcharts angular gauges?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, charts, amcharts

So I'm trying to display multiple angular gauges, and one works fine but the other displays 0.

[image: The two charts i get]

(I have changed the div number)

Here's the code i'm running...

Thanks ! :)

```js
<script>
var gaugeChart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv14", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "theme": "dark",
  "axes": [ {
    "axisThickness": 1,
    "axisAlpha": 0.2,
    "tickAlpha": 0.2,
    "valueInterval": 20,
    "bands": [ {
      "color": "#ff0000",
      "endValue": 65,
      "startValue": 0
    }, {
      "color": "#f5faf9",
      "endValue": 120,
      "startValue": 65
    }, {
      "color": "#84b761",
      "endValue": 300,
      "innerRadius": "95%",
      "startValue": 120
    } ],
    "bottomText": "0 km/h",
    "bottomTextYOffset": -20,
    "startValue": -80,
    "endValue": 300
  } ],
  "arrows": [ {} ],
  "export": {
    "enabled": false
  }
} );

setInterval( randomValue, 100 );

// set random value
function randomValue() {
  var value3 = Math.round(-4 +  Math.random() );
  var value4 = -4;
  if ( gaugeChart ) {
    if ( gaugeChart.arrows ) {
      if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ] ) {
        if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue ) {
          gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue( value3 );
          gaugeChart.axes[ 0 ].setBottomText( value4 + " subs yesterday" );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<script>
var gaugeChart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv13", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "theme": "dark",
  "axes": [ {
    "axisThickness": 1,
    "axisAlpha": 0.2,
    "tickAlpha": 0.2,
    "valueInterval": 20,
    "bands": [ {
      "color": "#ff0000",
      "endValue": 65,
      "startValue": 0
    }, {
      "color": "#f5faf9",
      "endValue": 120,
      "startValue": 65
    }, {
      "color": "#84b761",
      "endValue": 300,
      "innerRadius": "95%",
      "startValue": 120
    } ],
    "bottomText": "0 km/h",
    "bottomTextYOffset": -20,
    "endValue": 300
  } 

],
  "arrows": [ {} ],
  "export": {
    "enabled": false
  }
} );

setInterval( randomValue2, 100 );

// set random value
function randomValue2() {
  var value1 = Math.round(53 +  Math.random() );
  var value2 = 53;
  if ( gaugeChart ) {
    if ( gaugeChart.arrows ) {
      if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ] ) {
        if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue ) {
          gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue( value1 );
          gaugeChart.axes[ 0 ].setBottomText( value2 + " follows yesterday" );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it's a math conflict or just a syntax error somewhere, and by deleting one the other starts working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the variable in your second gauge chart and also change it in the associated random function. Right now you're using `gaugeChart` for both return values in AmCharts.makeChart, so the second chart is being used.

```
var gaugeChart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv14", {
  // stuff
});

function randomValue() {
 // ...
 // variable references should point to gaugeChart
}

// change the name of this variable for this chart
var gaugeChart2 = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv13", {
  // stuff
});

function randomValue2() {
  // ...
  // change references to gaugeChart to gaugeChart2 or whatever name you gave it earlier
}
```

Demo:

```js
var gaugeChart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv14", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "theme": "dark",
  "axes": [ {
    "axisThickness": 1,
    "axisAlpha": 0.2,
    "tickAlpha": 0.2,
    "valueInterval": 20,
    "bands": [ {
      "color": "#ff0000",
      "endValue": 65,
      "startValue": 0
    }, {
      "color": "#f5faf9",
      "endValue": 120,
      "startValue": 65
    }, {
      "color": "#84b761",
      "endValue": 300,
      "innerRadius": "95%",
      "startValue": 120
    } ],
    "bottomText": "0 km/h",
    "bottomTextYOffset": -20,
    "startValue": -80,
    "endValue": 300
  } ],
  "arrows": [ {} ],
  "export": {
    "enabled": false
  }
} );

setInterval( randomValue, 100 ); //consider setting the values directly in the chart if the value/text is meant to be static instead of calling this every tenth of a second.

// set random value
function randomValue() {
  var value3 = Math.round(-4 +  Math.random() ); //will always return -4 or -3. Consider removing the random part
  var value4 = -4;
  if ( gaugeChart ) {
    if ( gaugeChart.arrows ) {
      if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ] ) {
        if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue ) {
          gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue( value3 );
          gaugeChart.axes[ 0 ].setBottomText( value4 + " subs yesterday" );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var gaugeChart2 = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv13", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "theme": "dark",
  "axes": [ {
    "axisThickness": 1,
    "axisAlpha": 0.2,
    "tickAlpha": 0.2,
    "valueInterval": 20,
    "bands": [ {
      "color": "#ff0000",
      "endValue": 65,
      "startValue": 0
    }, {
      "color": "#f5faf9",
      "endValue": 120,
      "startValue": 65
    }, {
      "color": "#84b761",
      "endValue": 300,
      "innerRadius": "95%",
      "startValue": 120
    } ],
    "bottomText": "0 km/h",
    "bottomTextYOffset": -20,
    "endValue": 300
  } 

],
  "arrows": [ {} ],
  "export": {
    "enabled": false
  }
} );

setInterval( randomValue2, 100 ); //consider setting the values directly in the chart if the value/text is meant to be static instead of calling this every tenth of a second.

// set random value
function randomValue2() {
  var value1 = Math.round(53 +  Math.random() ); //will always return 53 or 54. Consider removing the Math.random part.
  var value2 = 53;
  if ( gaugeChart2 ) {
    if ( gaugeChart2.arrows ) {
      if ( gaugeChart2.arrows[ 0 ] ) {
        if ( gaugeChart2.arrows[ 0 ].setValue ) {
          gaugeChart2.arrows[ 0 ].setValue( value1 );
          gaugeChart2.axes[ 0 ].setBottomText( value2 + " follows yesterday" );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#chartdiv14, #chartdiv13 {
float: left;
width: 40%;
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/gauge.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv14"></div>
<div id="chartdiv13"></div>
```

Note that the arrow jittering is due to the `Math.round(.. + Math.random())` only returning the static value or static value + 1 (i.e. 53 or 54 in `randomValue2`). You might want to remove the random bit entirely and just use the constant if that's the desired result.

Comment: Sweet ! thanks so much, forgot about that variable :)